# python iterate multiple tags using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

i'm using python 3 and what i want to do is analyze an HTML page and extract some informations from specific tag.
This operation must be done multiple time. To get the HTML page i'm using beautifulsoup module and i can get correctly the html code by this way:

```
import urllib.request as req
import bs4

url = 'http://myurl.com'
reqq = req.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
reddit_file = req.urlopen(reqq)
reddit_data = reddit_file.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(reddit_data, 'lxml')
```

my html structure is the following:

```
<div class="first_div" id="12345">
  <div class="second_div">
    <div class="third_div">
        <div class="fourth_div">
            <div class="fifth_div">
                <a id="dealImage" class="checked_div" href="http://www.myurl.com/">
```

What i want to extract is the `href` value, and so `http://www.myurl.com/`

I tried using the find() function like this way and it works:

```
div = soup.find("div", {"class" : "first_div"})
```

But if i try to find directly the second div:

```
div = soup.find("div", {"class" : "second_div"})
```

it returns empty value

Thanks

**EDIT:**

the source html page is the following:

view-source:https://www.amazon.it/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-5_2d1d_page_1?gb_f_deals1=dealTypes:LIGHTNING_DEAL%252CBEST_DEAL%252CDEAL_OF_THE_DAY,sortOrder:BY_SCORE&pf_rd_p=82dc915a-4dd2-4943-b59f-dbdbc6482d1d&pf_rd_s=slot-5&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A11IL2PNWYJU7H&pf_rd_r=5Q5APCV900GSWS51A6QJ&ie=UTF8

What i have to extract is the `href` value from the `a-row dealContainer dealTile` div class

Comment: `find` Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given criteria.

Comment: but `findAll` Extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given criteria. You can specify the name of the Tag and any attributes you want the Tag to have.

Comment: what's the real url you are trying to extract from that link?

Answer (score 0):

`find` Return only the first child of this Tag matching the given criteria.

But `findAll` Extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given criteria. You can specify the name of the Tag and any attributes you want the Tag to have.

Here if you want to extract all `href` so you need to use `for` loop:

```
href = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "first_div"})
for item in href:
    print(img.get('href'))
```

Comment: so you need to share the html source or link directly to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Css selector which is much faster.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

reddit_data='''<div class="first_div" id="12345">
  <div class="second_div">
    <div class="third_div">
        <div class="fourth_div">
            <div class="fifth_div">
                <a id="dealImage" class="checked_div" href="http://www.myurl.com/">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(reddit_data, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select(".first_div a[href]"):
    print(item['href'])
```